# JAX-RS Jersey simple example runs on Standard Tomcat 8 but not TomEE 1.7.1

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, tomcat8, apache-tomee

Here is my JAX-RS jersey Example-Code:

HelloRest.java:

```
package com.test.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloRest {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getHelloWorld() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

RestApplicationConfig.java:

```
package com.test.rest;

import com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplicationConfig extends PackagesResourceConfig {
    public RestApplicationConfig() {
        super("com.test.rest");
    }
}
```

gradle dependency:

```
compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:1.19'
```

When I start a standard tomcat 8 and deploy the application, it works perfect.

But when I do the same with a standard TomEE Webprofile a get a strange error message when accessing /rest/hello:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet com.test.rest.RestApplicationConfig threw exception
    org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [com] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [com].
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.getInitializedExtension(CDIExtension.java:182)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactory.<init>(CDIComponentProviderFactory.java:95)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.initialize(CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.java:76)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.configure(WebComponent.java:572)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.configure(ServletContainer.java:332)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:604)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [com] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [com].
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:819)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
    org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:156)
    javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension$2.stepInto(CDIExtension.java:295)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.diveIntoJNDIContext(CDIExtension.java:272)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.lookupJerseyConfigJNDIContext(CDIExtension.java:292)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.getInitializedExtension(CDIExtension.java:180)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactory.<init>(CDIComponentProviderFactory.java:95)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.initialize(CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.java:76)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.configure(WebComponent.java:572)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.configure(ServletContainer.java:332)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:604)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087670/how-can-i-integrate-jersey-with-tomee

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with jersey and TomEE Webprofile: http://tomee.apache.org/tip-jersey-client.html

They suggest to use cxf instead (which worked fine for me).